# Proving convergence of series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}u_{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I was asked to prove that the series; $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}u_{n}$ converges, given that,

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}n^{p}u_{n}=A<\infty$ and $p>1$.

The proof of this is:

*If $u_{n}<\frac{A}{n^{p}}$ then applying the integral test shows convergence.*

This may be a stupid question but why is it that we are able to make the assumption $u_{n}<\frac{A}{n^{p}}$ ?

Thanks.

Comment: We are not. But $|u_n|<(|A|+1)/n^p$ for every $n$ large enough, and this suffices.

Comment: @Did I'm not sure but is it enough to say that for sufficiently large $n$,  $|u_{n}|<\frac{|A|+1}{n^{p}}<1$ and then apply the comparison test?

Comment: "is it enough to say that..." Actualy "it" exactly says that (except that $\frac{|A|+1}{n^{p}}<1$ is offtopic). To conclude, you should know and use the convergence of the series $\sum\limits_n\frac{1}{n^{p}}$.

Comment: @Did Ok thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Besides direct comparison, you have $ u_n \sim A / n^p $ hence $\sum u_n$ converges by limit comparison with $\sum A/ n^p.$